# Как решить эту проблему [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)

Tags: python, django

Выдает такую ошибку при попытке отправки сообщения с помощь яндекс smtp
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)
Ошибка выходит в try except`class PostSuccessfullyView(DetailView):
template_name = 'post/created.html'
model = Post

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    user = self.request.user
    email = user.email
    header_field = self.object.header_field

    html = render_to_string('post/created.html',
                            {'header_field': header_field,
                             'user': user
                             }
                            )
    print(html)
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject=f'{header_field} subscription',
        body='',
        from_email='khegaivyacheslavA@yandex.ru',
        to=['khegaivyacheslavA@yandex.ru']
    )
    msg.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
    try:
        msg.send()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return context`
```

Много где видел поставить Verify = False, но в таком случае куда его пихнуть ?